# Why will my legend not move in Python

Tags: python, legend-properties

I had to create a simple graph to learn the properties of graphing making in python. One of those properties is legend placement. The code for such is ax.legend(loc="some number"). The different numbers you put in that piece of code I mention determine where the legend is placed. However, no matter what number I put, my legend never changes position. Is there a deeper issue that I am missing or could there just be something wrong with my program?

```
def line_plot():
    x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,30)
    cosx=np.cos(x)
    sinx=np.sin(x)
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x), c='r', lw=3)
    ax1.plot(x,np.cos(x), c='b', lw=3)
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    ax1.legend(["cos","sin"])
    ax1.legend(loc=0);
    ax1.set_xlim([-3.14, 3.14])
    ax1.set_xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi])
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(['-'+r'$\pi$', '-'+r'$\pi$'+'/2',0, r'$\pi$'+'/2', r'$\pi$'])
    plt.show()

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    line_plot()
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Are you using matplotlib?

Comment: My apologies, yes, I am using numpy and matplotlib. Also, someone has answered my question. Thank you for taking the time to inquire and respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plot your data you need to give them a `label` in order for the legend to appear. If you do not do this then you get `UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.` and you wont be able to move your legend. So you can easily change this by doing the following:

```
def line_plot():
    x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,30)
    cosx=np.cos(x)
    sinx=np.sin(x)
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(x,np.sin(x), c='r', lw=3,label='cos') #added label here
    ax1.plot(x,np.cos(x), c='b', lw=3,label='sin') #added label here
    ax1.set_xlabel('x')
    ax1.set_ylabel('y')
    #ax1.legend(["cos","sin"]) #don't need this as the plots are already labelled now
    ax1.legend(loc=0);
    ax1.set_xlim([-3.14, 3.14])
    ax1.set_xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi])
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(['-'+r'$\pi$', '-'+r'$\pi$'+'/2',0, r'$\pi$'+'/2', r'$\pi$'])
    plt.show()

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    line_plot()
```

This gives the plot below. Now changing the value of `loc` changes the position of the legend.

[image]

EDIT:

1) I gave each set of data you plotted their own `label`. Then when you get to the line `ax1.legend(loc=0)` matplotlib then sets the legend to include these labels on the legend. This is the most 'pythonic' way of plotting the legend.

Comment: Thank You David for your help. I looked at the code and I have 2 questions

1) What was the significance to your action above commented "added labels here"

2) I attempted to input a different location number for the legend and it still does not move as you change the number. Is there a reason behind such?

Comment: You have 2 more questions? If they're related to this code then ask away.

Comment: I edited my original comment above to include my questions

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your first question. As for your second, if you just copy and paste the code in my answer and only change the value of `loc` from 0 to 1, does this move the legend?

Comment: Actually, yes. When I copied and pasted the code again and then changed the number each time before running the code, the graph would show the respective change. Idk, what was going on earlier but it appears ok now. Thank you.

Also, thank you for further explaining the change regarding the label. I appreciate the help.